# send props to when pressed button react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to send prop to other component When I clicked button. I cant send it. I get the Id when I am mapping movies but, I get undefined In movies class.

```
 exampleList= movies.map((x, index) => {
        return (
            
            <View key={index} style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('list'), <Movies movieId={x._id.$oid}/>}}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{x.movieName}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    })
```

```
    return (
        <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#COE6E7' }}>
            {exampleList}
        </ScrollView>
    );
```

```
export default class Movies extends React.Component {

   componentDidMount(){ 
        console.log(this.props.movieId)       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, if you ask with just a few snippets of code, your problem is difficult to figure out. For React-Native it is always good if you insert the hole code into an expo snack -> https://snack.expo.io/ and provide a running app till the point you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('list', {movieId : x._id.$oid})}
```

Then in Movies Screen when you will

```
console.log(this.props.movieId) // This will output MOVIE_ID
```